# Changing only schema, from public to another, with shp2pgsql

Tags: shp2pgsql

For example `shp2pgsql myGeoms.shp | more`  produce a SQL script that creates and inserts values into a `public.MagicName` table. I need to preserve `MagicName` and change only `public`  to `mySchema`... Is it possible?

---

- the `-h` summary say to use something as `shp2pgsql  myGeoms.shp mySchema.` but it produces `CREATE TABLE "mySchema".""` that is wrong ... And seems an "interface bug", because is a valid parameter but produces invalid output.
- this question [**is not** about `mySchena.myTableName`](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/189846/shp2pgsql-how-to-know-the-schema-table).

Comment: Bug reports should be submitted by contacting the vendor.

Comment: @Vince, please it is not for close, **it is not** a real bug, I edited to *seems an "interface bug"*.